# MacRuby. How to manage multiple frameworks. 0.10 and Latest

Tags: macruby

I am starting to write a MacRuby app. I installed some gems which i am interested in using. I get an error in xmlbase when trying to run.

/Library/Frameworks/MacRuby.framework/Versions/0.10/usr/lib/ruby/Gems/1.9.2/gems/builder-3.0.0/lib/builder/xmlbase.rb:in `_indent': undefined method`*' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

I am using the 0.10 version of the framework. I downloaded the latest daily version to see if its been fixed but when my app runs its still calling the old 0.10 version. How do i get it to reference the newer version. Is this something in Xcode to something specific to MacRuby. Can i use RVM to do this?

Also anyone have any ideas if this has been fixed in a more recent version. The code i am using is as follows. You'll need a bet fair account to test!

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'betfairapi-savon'

class BetFairTest
     def self.test
        api = BetfairAPI.new
        username = 'username'
         password = 'pass'
         response = api.login(username, password, 82, 0, 0, nil)
         session_token = response.to_hash[:login_response][:result][:header][:session_token]
         all_markets = api.get_all_markets(session_token,1)
         api.keep_alive(session_token)
         api.logout(session_token)
    end
end
```

after the login i get the error

```
/Library/Frameworks/MacRuby.framework/Versions/0.10/usr/lib/ruby/Gems/1.9.2/gems/builder-3.0.0/lib/builder/xmlbase.rb:in `_indent': undefined method `*' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from /Library/Frameworks/MacRuby.framework/Versions/0.10/usr/lib/ruby/Gems/1.9.2/gems/builder-3.0.0/lib/builder/xmlmarkup.rb:281:in `_special:'
from /Library/Frameworks/MacRuby.framework/Versions/0.10/usr/lib/ruby/Gems/1.9.2/gems/builder-3.0.0/lib/builder/xmlmarkup.rb:254:in `instruct!:'
from /Library/Frameworks/MacRuby.framework/Versions/0.10/usr/lib/ruby/Gems/1.9.2/gems/savon-0.9.7/lib/savon/soap/xml.rb:166:in `builder'
from /Library/Frameworks/MacRuby.framework/Versions/0.10/usr/lib/ruby/Gems/1.9.2/gems/savon-0.9.7/lib/savon/soap/xml.rb:150:in `to_xml'
from /Library/Frameworks/MacRuby.framework/Versions/0.10/usr/lib/ruby/Gems/1.9.2/gems/savon-0.9.7/lib/savon/soap/request.rb:38:in `setup:'
from /Library/Frameworks/MacRuby.framework/Versions/0.10/usr/lib/ruby/Gems/1.9.2/gems/savon-0.9.7/lib/savon/soap/request.rb:23:in `initialize:'
from /Library/Frameworks/MacRuby.framework/Versions/0.10/usr/lib/ruby/Gems/1.9.2/gems/savon-0.9.7/lib/savon/client.rb:79:in `request:'
from /Library/Frameworks/MacRuby.framework/Versions/0.10/usr/lib/ruby/Gems/1.9.2/gems/betfairapi-savon-1.0.1/lib/betfairapi-savon.rb:17:in `login:'
from /Users/barry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestApp-djtngswdhcnqvgdwihommmloripf/Build/Products/Debug/TestApp/Contents/Resources/BetFairTest.rb:20:in `test'
```

Cheers,
Barry.

Comment: I don't have a bet fair account, so I can't help you with the code, but could you post how you installed the latest version, what the results of `which macruby` are. Also, you mentioned Xcode. Are you starting with the MacRuby template and then clicking Build and Run?